# SQL Server 2005 IF...ELSE incorrect execution

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5266.00 (X64)

I am not sure what did I miss in below SQL. Can somebody find out what is the problem?

Here it goes -

```
create table my_temp
(
    col1 varchar(10)
)

--===================== the first block is executed
IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'my_temp') and Name = 'col2')
    begin
        select 'alter table my_temp add col2 bit'
        --alter table my_temp add col2 bit
    end    
else
    begin
        select 'update my_temp set col2 = null'
        --update my_temp set col2 = null
    end

--====================== the second block is executed

IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'my_temp') and Name = 'col2')
    begin
        --select 'alter table my_temp add col2 bit'
        alter table my_temp add col2 bit
    end    
else
    begin
        --select 'update my_temp set col2 = null'
        update my_temp set col2 = null
    end
```

I am confused that the same IF statement executes different code blocks.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results.   When I run your code, the first code block gets executed in both IF statements.   You are probably misinterpreting what you are seeing.

Comment: I confirmed that statement with my colleagues. It executes different blocks for the same 'IF' statement.
Again -  we are using SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5266.00 (X64).
Which SQL server version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

the problem related with batch 
if you executed your code like that, where you seperate batch with use of [GO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) statement

```
 create table my_temp
(
    col1 varchar(10)
)
GO
-- rest of script
```

then you will run your query each time `ELSE` part will executed because table is created

if you executed whole script first time with out `GO` statement then `IF` part will executed because at that time table will not create

Once you separate the QUERY table creation and other code then always `ELSE` part will executed

Comment: I don't think 'GO' statement has anything to do with it. 
1) Just create that table separately. 
2) Make sure it has been created. 
3) run first block of the code and check which code block it executes. 
4) run second block of the code and check which code block it executes.
 I found it executes different code blocks for the same IF statement.

Comment: @ShweKhine please try with `GO` and i tried to explain in my answer because it is working for me :)